# Batch file to delete AVI files from specific named folders

Tags: batch-file

am looking to tidy up a full archive drive by deleting unwanted video (AVI) files.

What I need to do is delete AVI files from within folders and sub-folders of a main directory. However, I don't want to delete AVI files from within any folder whose folder name contains the text "PG" - typically of the form "G1244A PG Report" but the identifying code (in this case "G1244A") may vary in length.
Thanks.

Added after @tftd comment:
Here's my effort so far (decided to move the vids, not delete them). Seems to work OK but not very elegant:

```
FOR /d /r %%d IN (*) DO (
ECHO "%%~nxd"|FIND " PG " >NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO Non-PG folder...move  vids in "%%d"
       Set NONPGFOLDER=%%d
       ECHO !NONPGFOLDER!
       DIR  "!NONPGFOLDER!\*.avi"
       MOVE "!NONPGFOLDER!\*.avi" "C:\AVIfiles\"
)ELSE (ECHO     PG folder...do nothing in "%%d"
)
)

PAUSE
Exit
```

Comment: Hello @Tox and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a moment and read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). When asking questions, please provide code, error log and description of your problem. Otherwise we'd think you're trying get developers to work for you for free!

Comment: Hi @tftd. Thanks for the advice. Am completely new to StackOverflow. Have edited my question.

Comment: You are welcome. I upvoted :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service and with spending some minutes on searching, you would have found most likely the code by yourself required for this simple task asked very often.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%F in ('dir /A-D /B /S "F:\*.avi" 2^>nul') do (
    set "FilePath=%%~dpF"
    if "!FilePath:PG=!" == "!FilePath!" echo del /F "%%F"
)
endlocal
pause
```

The command **DIR** with the options `/A-D /B /S` returns a list of file names of AVI files found on drive `F:` with full path and without double quotes even for full file names with 1 or more spaces included.

The path of each file is assigned to an environment variable.

If this file path with all occurrences of `PG` case insensitive removed is equal the unmodified file path, no folder in file path contains `PG` and therefore this file can be deleted.

There is command **echo** before command **del** in above code to make it possible for you to verify the deletion list before using the batch file without **echo** and without **pause**.

An alternate solution as suggested by [Joey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73070/joey):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /R "F:\" %%F in (*.avi) do (
    set "FilePath=%%~dpF"
    if "!FilePath:PG=!" == "!FilePath!" echo del "%%F"
)
endlocal
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Comment: Use `for /r in (*.avi)` instead of using `for /f` over `dir` output. While you handle spaces correctly, this will still fail for file names with Unicode in them, depending on the font settings of the console window.